# Depth Estimation from two points

Tags: projection-matrices, computer-vision

How can i find depth under this condition.

1) Two 2D points with (x,y) and angle of rotation is know in Y axis with each other.

2) Center of rotation is know of turn table.

Process is for 2D points is

1) Mark first point on image with some fiducial point that returns (x,y) in pixels and rotation angle of turn table.

2) Now rotate the turn table at certain amount i.e. more than 45 degree and mark the second point again using same fiducial point.

3) find depth from this information.

Since all (x,y) values are in pixels z components will be also in pixels.

Is it possible to do with simple trigonometry functions ?